# Boostrap.min.css not loading in django app after deploying to Azure Cloud

Tags: python, django, azure, django-templates, azure-web-app-service

My website is running perfectly on localhost but when I upload my code to Azure cloud it doesn't load `boostrap.min.css` due to its theme is not loading

On localhost:
[image: Local host image]

On Azure site
[image: Azure Screenshot]

Why it is not fetching the bootstrap themes on site?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the few workarounds that you can try :

Solution 1 :
In `urls.py` , Add this code

```cs
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and make sure that in your `settings.py`

```
DEBUG = True
```

Solution 2 :
There may be some causes like changing the settings.DEBUG to false or the installed packages overridden the runserver.
Here is the few steps you can try for the above causes :

1. Define the STATIC_ROOT variable in settings and point it to a directory on your file system and
2. If that directory do not exist, create it.
3. Run this command `python manage.py collectstatic`
4. Apply solution 1 as well.

Comment: where do i have to run collectstatic command in local host server or azure command

Comment: try in azure command

Comment: its still not working